# Getting the Average, Maximum and median Time Numpy Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, date, datetime

The numpy function below calculates the difference of time in each interval in seconds. I am trying to add a bit to the code where it calculates the `average,median,max,max index` of the `delta_s` calculated and then I want to convert the `average,median,max` into days, hours , minutes and seconds. How would I be able to do that?

```
import numpy as np 

dates= np.array(['2017-09-15 07:11:00' ,'2017-09-15 11:25:30', '2017-09-15 12:11:10', '2021-04-07 22:43:12', '2021-04-08 00:49:18'], 
                dtype="datetime64[ns]")

delta_s = np.diff(dates) // 1e9 # nanoseconds to seconds
#calculations
delta_avg = np.average(delta_s)
delta_median= np.median(delta_s)
delta_max = np.max(delta_s)
delta_max_index= np.argmax(delta_s)
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us he

Comment: you just basically have to figure out the math.. how do you calculate average,median,max , days,hours,minutes,seconds ----> then translate it to code.